# Extjs 4, How to send multiple metaData for multiple dynamic grids, using a single Json file

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, grid, extjs4.1

I need to create 8-10 grids on a single panel, using accordion Layout. All grids would be created dynamically using the metaData object in JSON and metachange listener event on my store and reconfigure my grid accordingly (Pretty standard process) . But is there a way to use a single JSON file containing metaData and Data of more than one grid. So that I can use multiple stores to read a single JSON.

Something Like this would be good:

```
"grid1" : 
{
"metaData" : {---"root":"data1"-----------}
},
"grid2" :
{
"metaData" : {----"root":"data2"----------}
},
"data1" : {------------------},
"data2" :  {-----------------}
```

I already tried using metaProperty tag in my store, but that approach doesn't seem to work for me(ExtJs 4.1.3) .

Store Proxy:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'MultiData.json',
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
      //  metaProperty : 'grid1', //Doesn't work, hence commented
    }
```

Store Listener:

```
 'metachange' :function (store, meta) { 
        Grid.reconfigure(store, meta.columns); 
    }
```

NOTE: The above code works perfectly when I have only one metaData and data tag in JSON

Comment: How are you performing the load of data?

Comment: Hi @mindparse , I have updated the question. I am using the commonly practiced method. And works fine for configuring a single grid from JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this :

1. Get all the data you need using a single Ext.Ajax Call
2. Split the data into parts as you need.
3. use store.loadData() to load directly to store. This should also trigger the metachange listener and configure the grid accordingly. If it doesn't you can use the configure() property of the grid : grid.reconfigure(store,columns)

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadData
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure